# pycharm multiple interpreters in same project?

Tags: python, pycharm

I work on a project involving a "scraping" part, and a "web" part.
I use scrapy framework for the scraping, flask framework for the web.

Is it possible to configure PyCharm within the same project to use 2 interpreters, one 2.7 for the scrapy part and one 3.x for the flask part ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently you can only have one interpreter per PyCharm project, but you can [open multiple projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/opening-multiple-projects.html). If you could split your code base to two projects, this would solve the problem.

Comment: thanks, I was hoping I may have overlooked a functionnality, I'll do that as the scraping part just fills a database the web aprt uses .-)

Comment: Not true actually. You CAN do it. Just not through the GUI. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40724089/737297

Comment: @MikeFurlender it can be done through the GUI now  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56875333/3185694